# How to find a set of integer vectors (of length L) such that all its subsets with size L are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request

Given a number $M\geq L$, how to find a set of $M$ vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}^{L}$, say $S=\{\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{a}_L\}$, such that:

1-All subsets of $S$ with size $L$ are linearly independent.

2- The elements of $S$ have small norms. (Actually, I want the vectors in $S$ to be near the origin).

Example: let L=3 and M=7, then a possible solution is $S=\{\, [1,0,0],\, [0,1,0],\, [0,0,1],\,[1,1,1],\,[1,2,3],\,[3,1,2],\,[2,3,1] \, \}$.

Note: I am interested in a procedure to find the set $S$. For instance, starting from $S=\{\, [1,0,0],\, [0,1,0],\, [0,0,1]\,\}$, how to add new vectors to $S$ such that the constraint 1 is not violated.